# In torch trepl on mac, the tab completion is not working. It works fine on the linux machine I have.

Tags: lua, torch

In torch trepl on mac, the tab completion is not working. It works fine on the linux machine I have. Any idea what could went wrong?

Comment: What if you start `luajit` and then do `ok, readline = pcall(require, 'readline')`? Is `ok` true? If not then print `readline` that will provide an error message.

Comment: ok is indeed false. The error is the following: 
error loading module 'readline' from file '~/torch/install/lib/lua/5.1/readline.so':
 dlopen(~/torch/install/lib/lua/5.1/readline.so, 6): Symbol not found: _rl_completion_suppress_append
  Referenced from: ~/torch/install/lib/lua/5.1/readline.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in ~/torch/install/lib/lua/5.1/readline.so

Comment: You should update your question with these precisions. Also: indicate what is your Mac OS version, as well as the outputs of `otool -L ~/torch/install/lib/lua/5.1/readline.so`.

Comment: Do you have Homebrew installed? If yes, and if you have `readline` installed (check with `brew list readline`) then it's possible that it introduces a conflict (i.e. when you install `trepl` it reads the header from Homebrew readline version which is more recent than Apple's libedit / readline one).